# Passing a parameter to a callback function

Tags: javascript

I needed to pass a parameter to a callback function in Javascript, so I did the following which creates an anonymous function as a string and then passes it:

```
var f = "var r = function(result) {do_render(" + i + ",result.name,result.data);}"
eval(f)
$.getJSON("analysis?file=" + getParameterByName('file') + "&step=" + i,r);
```

This doesn't seem like a great idea however. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you use `eval`?

Comment: `eval` is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

There's several techniques that you can use to do this. One of which is to create a new function which "seals off" one of the variables:

```
function myCallback(i, result) { ... }

function createCurriedFunction(i, func, context) {
  return function (result) { func.call(context, i, result); }
}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
  var curriedFunc = createCurriedFuncion(i, myCallback, this);
  $.getJSON(url, curriedFunc);
}
```

Context is the object for which the "this" will refer to in the callback function. This may or may not be needed for what you're doing; if not you can just pass in null.

There's actually a function that does exactly that called bind, and is used like

```
var curriedFunc = myCallback.bind(this, i), which will seal off the first variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having issues closing over `i` and to solve it used eval. Instead of that, simply close over it using an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) like this:

```
(function(i){
    //create a closure of the value of i
    //so that it takes the immediate value of it instead of the end value
    //based on the assumption i is from a loop iterator
    $.getJSON("analysis?file=" + getParameterByName('file') + "&step=" + i,
        function(result){
            do_render(i, result.name, result.data); 
        }
    );
})(i);//pass i into the IIFE in order to save its immediate value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
var url = "myurl";
$.getJSON(url, function(result){
    //callback function
});
```